# Why do we need separate openssl.rb file?

Tags: ruby, openssl

I want to understand why we need [openssl.rb](https://github.com/lian/bitcoin-ruby/blob/master/lib/bitcoin/ffi/openssl.rb) in [bitcoin-ruby](https://github.com/lian/bitcoin-ruby) project.
Is [Ruby SSL implementation](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/SSL.html) not enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right the core ruby has openssl as std-lib.   However, if you want to insure that a gem works as expected, you want to have it's dependencies tested against current versions of the gem so that when you do `gem install bitcoin-ruby` it will install a tested dependency chain.  Otherwise, how can you be sure the version of core ruby SSL has not changed something which might break the  installed version of `bitcoin-ruby`?

Here first part of std-lib core version of ruby 2.3

```
module OpenSSL
  class Digest

    alg = %w(DSS DSS1 MD2 MD4 MD5 MDC2 RIPEMD160 SHA SHA1)
    if OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER > 0x00908000
      alg += %w(SHA224 SHA256 SHA384 SHA512)
    end
```

Here is gem version for ruby 2.4.1

```
module OpenSSL
  class Digest

    alg = %w(MD2 MD4 MD5 MDC2 RIPEMD160 SHA1 SHA224 SHA256 SHA384 SHA512)
    if OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER < 0x10100000
      alg += %w(DSS DSS1 SHA)
    end
```

So right away we can see some different algorithm definitions. Not locking a bundle gem version would be a bad idea, especially for something as important as cryptography in bitcoin.